# Is the Bot Template window in Azure portal supposed to look like this?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to create a "QnA Bot" using Azure Portal. The "Bot Template" window shows several templates, including "QnA Bot", but there's no way to select it. Is this a bug?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QnA Bot creation has been accelerated now from QnA Maker portal directly, see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-qna-bot?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#create-a-qna-bot)

In the past, you could create a QnA Bot from Azure Portal but it may have been misleading as people did not see the link with QnA Maker product (so I guess now it's included in QnA Maker portal for this reason?).

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that I could use the QnA Maker site before I saw your answer, but the dialog shown in my screen shot still seems weird to me, as if it was a left-over or something.

Comment: Agree with you on that